# How to use multiple ref variables on same html element in react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ref

Here is the brief snippet of my functional component's render method(removed unnecessary code for brevity)

```
  return (
    <Draggable draggableId={id} index={index}>
      {(provided, snapshot) => (
        <>
          <div className="carditem" ref={provided.innerRef} {...provided.draggableProps} {...provided.dragHandleProps} onClick={onClick}>
            <span className="carditem_title">{card.title}</span>
            <i className="fas fa-pencil-alt edit_button" onClick={onEditClick} />
            {hasDescription && <i className="fas fa-align-left desc_tag" title="This card has a description" />}
          </div>
          {isEditing && showOverlay && <input className="card_edit" type="text" autoFocus />}
        </>
      )}
    </Draggable>
  );
```

On line 5, if you notice I have a

```
ref={provided.innerRef}
```

I want to get the x,y coordinate of `div` with `className="cardItem"` and therefore I want to add a ref to that element. But a ref already exists as shown above. **How can I add my own ref variable without breaking existing ref?**

Not sure if it helps, but I am using react-beautiful-dnd and which is where that `provided.innerRef` comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the callback to bind multiple refs

```
const refHanlder = el => {
  refA.current = el;
  refB.current = el;
}

ref={el => refHandler}
```

The callback is also used for Array of refs

```
ref={el => elementRef.current[x] = el}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One small question. how do I pass provided.innerRef into refHandler function?

Comment: @theprogrammer It's passed implicitly and if you want to make it a param, use `ref={el => refHandler(ref)}` with `const refHanlder = el  => () => {`